# GSON Generate Plugin не правильно работает

Tags: android

GSON Generate Plugin не правильно работает

У меня есть массив Json из 10 объектов.

При генерации через плагин GSON массива нет. Есть только объект в кол-во 1 штуки Что делать?

Comment: Приведите объект к ArrayList<Object>. Посмотрите результат.

Comment: спс) заработало